# How to call a function within a class from another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish the following task.  I want to be able to call a function that is within a class in another file:

file1

```
export class Something {
  constructor() {
    ...
  }
  myFunction = () => {
    ...
  }
}
```

file2

```
import { Something } from 'file1';

export function theFunction() {
  if (condition met) {
    Something.myFunction(...) // The myFunction is saying it's not a function
  }
}
```

Comment: `new Something().myFunction(...)` you need to learn about static and non-static methods.

Comment: you probably need to either instantiate the class or make the function static

Comment: `myFunction ` is an *instance* method, not static

Comment: Instance/non static methods cannot be called using class name.

Comment: Looks like updating the function to use static solved the issue.  Can one of you post the answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Answers don't belong in the question--there's already an accepted answer; if that answer is not sufficient you can answer your own question.

Comment: @DaveNewton I accepted the answer below, but also updated my question with the overall consensus to make sure I was understanding correctly.  I didn't think that would be an issue.

Comment: @pingeyeg Answers belong in answers, not in questions. That's the site format. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
class Canonical {      /* in ES5 */ function Canonical() {}
  myMethod() { ... }                Canonical.prototype.myMethod = function() { ... };
}
```

You can call that like this:

```js
Canonical.prototype.myMethod();
// Or, to call it as a method on anObject
Canonical.prototype.myMethod.call(anObject);
```

What you have created however is not a method, but a property created on each individual instance, that happens to be a function:

```js
class Unusual {                 /* in ES5 */ function Unusual() {
  myFunction = () => { ... };                  this.myFunction = function() { ... };
}                                            }
```

It only exists on instances and therefore you have to create one to call it:

```js
new Unusual().myFunction();
```

However I can't recommend this way of defining a "method", unless you specifically need it to be pre-bound. That is useful in `React.Component` classes, but now with React hooks that use case is waning.

```js
class Test {
  constructor() { this.a = ''; }
  myMethod() { console.log(this.a); }
  myFunction = () => console.log(this.a);
}
const methodReference = new Test().myMethod;
try {
  methodReference(); /* This will not work.
                        This is where an instance property can be advantageous */
} catch (ex) { console.error(ex.message); }
const functionReference = new Test().myFunction;
functionReference();
```